# Reassign Makefile variable for target

Tags: makefile, gnu-make, target

This is a simple Makefile:

```
    ...
VAR    := 
FLAGS  := --flag=$(VAR)

target_1: VAR = 1
target_1: $(DEPS_1)
    $(CMD) $(FLAGS)
    ...

target_2: VAR = 2
target_2: $(DEPS_2)
    $(CMD) $(FLAGS)
    ...
```

I want to reassign variable `VAR` to make `make` recalculate value of `FLAGS` to use it for different targets, is there a way to do something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use simple expansion for `FLAGS`:

```
FLAGS  := --flag=$(VAR)
```

is wrong; you want this:

```
FLAGS  = --flag=$(VAR)
```

If you expand `FLAGS` immediately, the all the variables are expanded to whatever their value is at that point in the makefile.  There is no opportunity to redo that later, because the variable reference is gone: it's replaced with the value.